# Why can't I appendChild to the specified DIV?

Tags: javascript

In some cases it is possible for me to use appendChild() to add to a div, but in other cases it does not work and I am trying to understand why:

**Works:** I have other code examples where something like the following code works fine:

```
function fnAppend(){
   var oNewNode = document.createElement("LI");
   oList.appendChild(oNewNode);
   oNewNode.innerText="List node 5";
}
```

**Does not Work:** I know this is a totally different example, but I presume the difference is subtle. I am pulling this code from an existing project I am working in, so I can not change the **FieldSet function** in anyway, rather I am trying to understand how to make it work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">     
        function Fieldset() {

            this.id = "";
            this.content = document.createElement("DIV");
            this.content.id = "content";
            this.title = "Title";

            this.getFieldset = function() {
                var div = document.createElement("DIV");
                div.id = this.id;
                var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
                //var fieldset = document.createElement("DIV");
                //fieldset.id = "fieldset";
                var header = document.createElement("DIV");
                header.id = "header";
                span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.title));
                header.appendChild(span);
                div.appendChild(header);
                div.appendChild(this.content);
                //div.appendChild(fieldset);

                return div;
            }
        }

        var fieldset = new Fieldset();
        fieldset.id = "newid";
        fieldset.title = "new title";

        org_div1.appendChild(fieldset.getFieldset());

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="fieldset()">
        <div id='org_div1'> The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: oNewNode.innerText might should be oNewNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("List node 5"))

Comment: Where do you initialize "org_div1" ?

Comment: Why do I need to initialize org_div1 if it's just a div tag? It is possible I might have to do this, I just don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line containing `onload="fieldset()"`. `fieldset` is an object, not a function, so you can't execute it directly.

You can get what you're aiming for by wrapping the code you want to run in a function, like this:

```
function createFieldset () {
    var fieldset = new Fieldset();
    fieldset.id = "newid";
    fieldset.title = "new title";

    org_div1.appendChild(fieldset.getFieldset());
}
```

Then, execute this function from the body tag, like this:

```
<body onload="createFieldset()">
```

Two points should be mentioned:

1. As Steve H. mentioned, you should initialize org_div1 before using it. Relying on elements being reachable through a global variable with that ID is not 100% reliable in all browsers
2. Your code inserts the new content before the static content, not after. You want to use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore)

In light of those two points, I would replace the last line of your script with this:

```
var org_div1 = document.getElementById("org_div1");
org_div1.parentNode.insertBefore(fieldset.getFieldset(), org_div1);
```